# Unable to find element by the value in double quotes that is displayed for checkbox using selenium in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to select the checkbox that is next to the word "Sheriff" using the word itself. None of the CSS selectors in the chunk below remain constant across all the webpages I'd like to automate.

```html
<li>
<input id="chkSelectField9" type="checkbox" value="0112" onclick="javascript:CheckAllStatus();"> == $0
"Sheriff"
</li>
```

the webpage: https://www.enr-scvotes.org/SC/Abbeville/64659/183591/en/search-contests.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to locate the element with XPath and add a condition before clicking :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[.="Sheriff"]/input'))
)
element.click()
```